# Nodejs running function on background

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, async-await

I’ve nodes program which I need to run two function in the beginning of the program
And later on access the function results, currently with await each function at a time this works,
However in order to save a time and not waiting to `GetService` and `GetProcess` as I need the data later on in the project 
It takes about 4 seconds to get this data and I want to run it on the background as I don’t need the results immediately,
How I can do it in node js, If I run `promise.all` It would wait until the `getService` and `getProcess`  and then go to rest of the program.

an example

```
function main() {

//I want to run this both function in background to save time
let service = await GetServices();
this.process = await GetProcess();


…..//Here additional code is running 

//let say that after 30 second this code is called
 Let users = GetUser(service);

 Let users = GetAdress(this.process);
}
```

im actually running yeoman generator 
https://yeoman.io/authoring/
https://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html

```
export default class myGenerator extends Generator {

//here I want run those function in background to save time as the prompt to the user takes some time (lets say user have many questions...) 
async initializing() {
    let service = await GetServices();
    this.process = await GetProcess();
}

async prompting() {
    const answers = await this.prompt([
      {
        type: "input",
        name: "name",
        message: "Your project name",
        default: this.appname // Default to current folder name
      },
      {
        type: "confirm",
        name: "list",
        choises: this.process //here I need to data from the function running in background
      }
    ]);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the asynchronous operation but not await it yet:

```
function suppressUnhandledRejections(p) {
  p.catch(() => {});
  return p;
}

async function main() {
  // We have to suppress unhandled rejections on these promises. If they become
  // rejected before we await them later, we'd get a warning otherwise.
  const servicePromise = suppressUnhandledRejections(GetServices());
  this.processPromise = suppressUnhandledRejections(GetProcess());

  // Do other stuff
  const service = await servicePromise;
  const process = await this.processPromise;
}
```

Also consider using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which returns a promise for the completion of all promises passed to it.

```
async function main() {
  const [ services, process, somethingElse ] = await Promise.all([
    GetServices(),
    GetProcess(),
    SomeOtherAsyncOperation(),
  ]);

  // Use the results.
}
```

Comment: thanks. 1. in case I cannot use async to the main , I can only use promise all ? with promise.all It will not wait to both function to finish and then process to `getServices` etc ?

Comment: @JennyM (1) You should be able to make `main()` async. What makes you think you can't? Just make sure you handle any rejections. (2) The promise returned by `Promise.all` becomes fulfilled when all promises passed in are fulfilled. The very act of _calling_ `GetServices()` and `GetProcess()` is what starts those operations; `Promise.all` only awaits the returned promises. It's not capable of actually starting any async operations itself. Therefore, the async operations will all proceed concurrently.

Comment: ok let me try it :) , btw which way is preferred(or you would use), the first or the second ?

Comment: @JennyM That depends on what `//Here additional code is running` actually is, which I can't see in your question.

Comment: @cdhowie - please see my edit, I want to run the functions in background and start generator prompt and later on from the prompt access to the result of the prompts, I put some minimal example which ilustrate the  point

Comment: @JennyM It's not clear how this can be accomplished exactly, because an array is passed to `this.prompt()` which needs the values ahead of time. If `default` or `choices` is allowed to be a promise, then we have some options, but I'm not familiar enough with Yeoman to know if this is the case.

Comment: @JennyM The only way I can see to do this is to call `this.prompt()` multiple times.

Comment: what do you mean by calling multiple times? can you give some example in your answer and i'll try? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume that `getServices()` may take 3 seconds and `getProcess()` may take 4 seconds, so if you run these both functions at the same time you will be returned in total 4 seconds with the return values from both promises.

You can execute the code while this process is running in the background there will be a callback when the promises resolved, your late functions will be called at this stage.

Check the below simple example;

```js
let service;
let process;

function main() {

    // Both functions will execute in background
    Promise.all([getServices(), getProcess()]).then((val) => {

        service = val[0];
        process = val[1];

        console.log(service, process);

        // Aafter completed this code will be called
        // let users = GetUser(service);
        // let users = GetAdress(process);
        console.log('I am called after all promises completed.')
    });

    // Current example.
    // let service = await GetServices();
    // this.process = await GetProcess();

    /* Code blocks.. */
    console.log('Code will execute without delay...')
}

function getServices() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("service is returned")
        }, 3000);
    });
}

function getProcess() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("process is returned")
        }, 4000);
    });
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what who you need, you have to understand [the event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).

Nodejs is designed to work in a single thread unlike languages like go, however nodejs handle proccess on different threads. so you can use nextTick () to add a new event to the main thread and it will be executed at the end of the whole block.

```
    function main() {

    //I want to run this both function in background to save time
    let service = await GetServices();
    this.process = await GetProcess();


    …..//Here additional code is running 

    //Let say that after 30 second this code is called
     Let users = GetUser(service);

     Let users = GetAdr(this.process);
    } 


 function someFunction(){
 // do something...
  }
 main();
 process.nextTick(someFunction());// happens after all main () processes are terminated...
```